# Can workspace have storage size more than 10GB when using Power BI pro in shared capacity?

Tags: powerbi

What does it mean by total storage size in Power BI pro is 10GB?

Is this per user? So if there are 10 pro license then each user has 10GB or all users combined have 10GB? Or 10*10=100GB?

As per this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-manage-your-data-storage-in-power-bi#shared-capacity-limits

> Shared capacity limits
>
> For workspaces in shared capacity:
>
> There is a per-workspace storage limit of 10 GB.
>
> Premium Per User (PPU) tenants have a 100 TB storage limit.
>
> When using a Pro license,
> the total usage can’t exceed the tenant storage limit of 10 GB
> multiplied by the number of Pro licenses in the tenant.

So does this mean that workspace cannot have more than 10GB storage irrespective of number of pro users on the tenant?

Answer (score 2):

Power Bi Pro user workspace storage limit is 10GB, which means that if you have deployed power BI dashboards with imbedded datasets, at max it can take 10GB of space for one Pro license.
Pro License user workspace cant be increased more than 10GB.

only way to increase the workspace of Pro license user is to increase the pro users license , as its **workspace = 10GB * # of pro users**

Capacity limits
Workspace storage limits, whether for My Workspace or an app workspace, depend on whether the workspace is in shared or Premium capacity.

Shared capacity limits
For workspaces in shared capacity:

There is a per-workspace storage limit of 10 GB.
Premium Per User (PPU) tenants have a 100 TB storage limit.
When using a Pro license, the total usage can’t exceed the tenant storage limit of 10 GB multiplied by the number of Pro licenses in the tenant.

for more details you can follow the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-manage-your-data-storage-in-power-bi

Comment: The link says per workspace limit is 10GB. Where does it say that this cam be increased?